# QTcpSocket создать один сокет на все приложение

Tags: qt, классы, qtcpsocket

Всем привет! как создать один QTcpSocket, который я бы мог использовать на всех классах(формах) приложения. Имеется ввиду у каждого класса свой

```
public slots:
    void sockReady();
    void sockDisc();
```

СпасибО!

Comment: создать глобальную переменную? (это конечно такое-себе решение, но думаю хватит)

Comment: через .h и .cpp extern QTcpSocket socket? можете пример привести, я хочу чтобы на всех формах работало и у каждой формы свой sockReady и sockDisc. Я в конструкторе делаю connect().  connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(sockReady()));
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(sockDisc())); и хочу чтобы сокет был один, а я создаю через socket = new QTcpSocket(this);. Спасибо!

Comment: Не нужно так на самом деле делать.Потому что когда данные прибегут, они будут всем скопированы. Но это пол беды. А при записи будет совсем проблема - данные могут перемешаться.
Какую задачу Вы решаете (только не говорите, что один сокет на всех - это решение, а не задача)?

Comment: задача вроде как обычная, есть QTcpServer многопоточный, с соединенной базой данных, который обрабатывает запросы приходящие от клиентов QTcpSocket. Все в ReadyRead() и Disconnected() заполнены ифами от JSON'a. Данные передаются в виде JSON объектов, есть все основные операции SQL. У клиента прописаны формы(разные классы) и находясь в них нужно как-то общаться с сервером. Или вы предлагаете создать один сокет в mainwindow и с ним обмениваться информацией по connect? думаю слишком сложно. Извините за столь тупые вопросы, я новичок. Спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужен один QTcpSocket. Где именно он будет - другое дело. Вокруг него лучше сделать обертку-диспетчер, которой уже и будут пользоваться другие и соединять это все connect - это нормально в Qt.

Comment: Спасибо! это же слишком сложно, если приложение будет развиваться. Я думал можно как-то другому сделать. Все равно спасибо за отзыв!